# Copying a range of formulas and pasting values to a selected row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a button that will copy a range of formulas and pasted their values starting in the selected cell.

My formula range is from U1:EN1.  I'd like to paste these values into and to the right of whichever cell is selected when the "Get New Data" button is clicked.

Below is what I have so far:

```
Sub Update_Quote_Data_5()
'
' Update_Quote_Data_5 Macro
'

'
    Range("U1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll ToRight:=-5
    Range("U9").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("U10").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with this:

```
Sub Update_Quote_Data_5_The_Sequel()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("U1:EN1")
    Set r2 = ActiveCell
    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To move to the cell below the previous ActiveCell:

```
Sub Update_Quote_Data_5_The_Sequel()
    Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
    Set r1 = Range("U1:EN1")
    Set r2 = ActiveCell
    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    r2.Offset(1, 0).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  That is exactly what I was trying to accomplish!

Comment: How do I make this un-select U1:EN1 and go to next cell below, @Gary's Student?

Comment: @ChrisManis  Do you want to go to **U2** or the cell below **ActiveCell**??

Comment: The cell below the ActiveCell, please.

Comment: In that case, all you need is to set the range r2 as `Set r2 = ActiveCell.Offset(1)`

Comment: I didn't explain that right.  With the above, it does everything I need, except it leaves U1:EN1 selected after it pastes into the active cell.  I'd just like to ammend this to un-select U1:EN1 and move to the cell below the active cell once finished pasting.

Comment: Also, I can't undo if I accidentally set the active cell to a wrong one.  Suggestions?

Comment: @ChrisManis  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: No, you cannot undo after the data is pasted by the code. The only thing you can do is, ask the user to confirm if the correct activecell is selected before pasting the copied data and if user confirms by clicking on Yes in the confirmation msg window, the code will paste the data otherwise it will exit the code. Also, I think you should use the line `Application.CutCopyMode = 0` just before the `End Sub` to deselect the copied range.

Comment: You guys absolutely ROCK!  Thank you very much @Gary'sStudent and @sktneer!

Answer (score 1):

You may also try something like this...

```
Sub Update_Quote_Data()
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = Range("U1:EN1")
ActiveCell.Resize(1, Rng.Columns.Count).Value = Rng.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering!

Comment: A clever approach that avoids copy/paste *(+1)*

Comment: Agreed.  My only issue with this answer is that it changes the format of the values pasted instead of keeping the destination cell format.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks! :)

Comment: @ChrisManis Yeah, that might be the case with this approach.